# Vue Store state variables - best practices for calculations

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm making a e-commerce site in VueJS and working on the shopping cart.

In the Store the state variables :

```
state: () => ({
   cart:[],
   totalPrice: 0,
   itemsInCart: 0
}),
```

"totalPrice" and "itemsInCart" all get calulcated when the "cart" variable is updated.

When I need the totalPrice i just call a getter that returns the "totalPrice" variable. All fine and dandy, but I'm asking if this is good practice at all.

Another way to do this would be to have a getter that runs through the cart array and returns the calculations from that, but then it would be called and run many times (unless it is cached ?) and the same with "itemsInCart" which would return a length of the cart array. Also called multiple times.

What is the best practice here? Keep them as variables and update them when the cart array is updated or having functions that runs through the cart array everytime the variable is needed? Or any other way?

The problem with how it is now is that the "cart update" function needs to do more than update the cart - it needs to calculate price and length aswell.

Comment: `totalPrice` and `itemsInCart` as getters is the best practice since the getters are considered as computed properties in the vuex store

Comment: Vue computed properties are not the same as getters from the store. If you are accessing store getters values through a computed property then the value from the getter is being cached and since getters are reactive the computed property will "react" to any change

Comment: @RobertoLangarica So in other words I can change the getter function to call an action for example that calulcates the totalPrice instead of having totalPrice as a stand-alone variable? (because it will be reactive and cached anyways?)

Comment: Yes you can do that. Just be aware that the caching happens in the computed property, if you access your getter outside the computed property then you should use another caching mechanism. [Here are the docs for computed properties](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)